# How to set breakpoint in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom-events, google-chrome-devtools

I have a `<select/>` element in the DOM, I want to pause the execution of the code when it's `onchange` event is fired. My goal is to determine the function that gets called when `onchange` is fired. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is debugger in your code

```
<select onChange={()=> {
  debugger;
  // ... your code
} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a debugger statement in your onChange function or add a console.log() function to know whether onChange is fired. Remember that you must open the dev tool to see the log and the js process will break in your debugger statement